# How can I change the table of contents' name in RMarkdown?

Tags: r-markdown, tableofcontents, renewcommand

I want to change the Table of Contents' name into my own language, as now it appears as `Contents`.

So far, I did change the caption for figures as follows:
`\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}`

But this command is not working for Contents, `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Taula de continguts}`

Comment: Are you using the `babel` package? Could you post a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: in the YAML:   toc-title: "Taula de continguts"